# record.submitFields() on Invoice doesn't work: SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to use record.submitFields() on an invoice record, but this most simple invokation throws the following error:

ERROR :
** Netsuite Error Info **
Code: SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT
Details: id
Reference ID:
Stack Trace: Error at suitescript/resources/javascript/record/recordImpl.js:156:24 at Object.submitFields (suitescript/resources/javascript/record/recordImpl.js:154:30) ...

Here is my statement issued from a scheduled script:

`var id = record.submitFields({ type: record.Type.INVOICE, id: 16963107, values: { 'memo': 'Hello World' }, options: { enableSourcing: false, ignoreMandatoryFields: true } });`

I've Googled for resolutions but nothing seems to come up other than suggestions that my field needs to be  available for inline editing. We have that enabled in our account and I've tried on several fields, all of which produce the error. I must be overlooking something simple and any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not mistyping something ? Because your code should be fine. Also, the ID you are indicating, is it hardcoded in your code ? Or coming from a variable ? If it is coming from a Variable, make sure that the variable has a Value.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The example I gave is a one-line scheduled script to simplify my question. This one-line script does not work and produces the same error. I used the memo field as an example because it is a native field and should be a ready-to-use example if someone in Stackoverflow land should replace the value of the id parameter with an invoice id of their own. :-)  I'm wondering if it has something to do with a recent upgrade, or our particular environment (SB). I've tried this code using various ids, and also using native and custom fields. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

There must be another User Event script, that executes at record.submitFields.
Either you can exclude the Map reduce context from that user event or do validation for the id field.
I changed my version from 2.1 to 2.x for the Map reduce and in the map stage just tried record.submit for a memo field.
it showed the correct error as missing id field at the User Event.